# KendoMobile prevent click from bubbling

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am trying to do something like this.

```
<a data-target="main-view" href="/home/index">
<div class="inner_div">Click here should not bubble to the container anchor</div>
</a>
```

The Code that I tried:

```
$('.inner_div').click(function(e) {
   $(this).addClass('measure');
   //e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   //return false;
});
```

I tried jquery stopPropagation, preventDefault etc. But it doent work here as Kendo is doing something here on which I dont have control to prevent default.

Can anybody suggest a way of doing it ?

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried here so that we can help you better?

Comment: I think in not a propagation issue; your div is wrapped from an anchor with href so fire first the href action